# MySQL internal order of operations in SELECT query

Tags: mysql

What is the internal order of operations in a MySQL `SELECT` query and a relational query?

For instance, a `SELECT` query to a single table:

```
SELECT `name`
FROM `users` 
WHERE `publication_count`>0
ORDER BY `publication_count` DESC
```

I know that at first all table fields are fetched and then only `name` field is left at the end. Does it happen before or after the condition in `WHERE` is applied? When is `ORDER BY` applied?

A relational query using two tables:

```
SELECT `users`.`name`, `post`.`text` 
FROM `users`, `posts` 
WHERE `posts`.`author_id`=`user`.`id` 
ORDER BY `posts`.`date` DESC
```

Same question. What happens after what? (I know that at first the Cartesian product is generated)

Comment: What does EXPLAIN tell you that might help answer these questions?

Comment: Way to broad to explain here..

Answer (score 0):

Processing regarding your example simplifying the rules goes as follow:

```
 1. FROM     -- all elements in list (including multiple tables)
 2. WHERE    -- discard rows not matching conditions
 3. SELECT   -- output rows are computed (not fetched)
 4. ORDER BY -- sort output rows
```

Also, you shouldn't be using old-fashioned implicit join syntax in `WHERE` condition. Instead, please use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM users
INNER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.author_id
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any link to documentation or something?

Comment: @user2513149 there's no information I could find on MySQL reference manual, but I assume this should work very similarly to PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Comment: "Thank you. But is there any link to documentation or something?" @user2513149 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/

Comment: @RaymondNijland, there is only an index of topics on the page you provided. What page exactly describes a `SELECT` query?

Comment: "What page exactly describes a SELECT query?" Chapter 12 How MySQL Performs Different Selects but you also need the MySQL source code to study

Comment: @user2513149 That index is probably the closest you'll get to a specific answer; while what this answer describes is accurate _as far as end result/logic is concerned_, the reality/implementation is much more complicated. MySQL (and many other SQL implementations) typically use the conditions in the FROM (and indexes involved) to reduce the number of intermediate results "materialized". Under certain circumstances ("covering" indexes), tables in the FROM can be not even directly accessed.